# ValueInjector not mapping IDs from view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, valueinjecter

I'm using [ValueInjecter](http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/) to inject data from my view model to my entity framework model, and for non Ids such as strings it works great.  For some reason it is not mapping the IDs from select lists in my view, once mapped they show up as null.  Any ideas why?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //inject the view model into db model
            Core.Models.User user = new User();
            user.InjectFrom(model);
```

View Model

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Organization is required")] 
    [DisplayName("Organization")]
    public Guid OrganizationId
    { get; set; }
```

Entity framework model Property

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public Nullable<global::System.Guid> OrganizationId
    {
        get
        {
            return _OrganizationId;
        }
        set
        {
            OnOrganizationIdChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("OrganizationId");
            _OrganizationId = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
            ReportPropertyChanged("OrganizationId");
            OnOrganizationIdChanged();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because they are of different types `Guid` and `Nullable<Guid>`

Comment: Chuck Norris saved the day!  Can't believe I didn't see that.

Comment: I'm assuming its designed that way, but it would be great it the ViewModel could not be nullable, while its common the domain model is.